# Swift equivalent of inputStream

Tags: java, swift, parse-platform

---

### Heading

I am converting my android app into a IOS app using swift 2.0 and Parse Backend, I would just like to know the equivalent to this code:

---

Code

---

```
InputStream rawData = (InputStream) new URL(https_url).getContent();
Bitmap UniqueQRCode = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(rawData);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

// Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100
UniqueQRCode.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: I don't know what is your `UniqueQRCode` class. But you can search the way to download an image file in swift. There is no equivalent way to convert this code snip to swift language.

Comment: UniqueQRCode is the Bitmap

Comment: My mistake, because you declare a variable with uppercase first character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to do an asynchronous call on iOS. That will lead to more responsive applications.

Here is a simple example to download an image from the web and display it in a `UIImageView`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let url = NSURL(string: "https://mozorg.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/firefox/new/header-firefox-high-res.d121992bf56c.png") {
            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url)) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil && data != nil { // Needs better error handling based on what your server returns
                    if let image = UIImage(data: data!) {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            self.imageView.image = image
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

If you run this on iOS 9 then you do need to set `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to `YES` in the application's `Info.plist`. There are lots of postings about that in more detail.